# Universal bucket in Google Cloud Platform for content, which would determine the user's location and serve content from the closest server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-public-dns, google-cloud-cdn

I am a mobile application developer. I use Google Cloud bucket to store 10-second videos and photos that I use in the application. Thousands of users use the application every day, and I want to use a CDN to ensure that the content of the application is delivered to users with minimum delays and maximum speed.

At the moment, I have only found an opportunity to create a bucket within one region to choose from: the USA, Europe, and Asia. How to create a universal bucket in Google Cloud Platform for storing application content, which would determine the user's location and serve content from the server closest to the user?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://cloud.google.com/cdn/ is a feature for you?
On other terms: Just use a proper CDN.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802631/is-google-cloud-storage-an-automagical-global-cdn

tl;dr: don't worry about it as Google will handle edge caching of objects in Google Cloud Storage anyway - [as per this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/serving-static-files):

*'Cloud Storage essentially works as a content delivery network. This does not require any special configuration because by default any publicly readable object is cached in the global Cloud Storage network.'*